# Doctrine ORM Error: A Foreign Key Constraint Fails

Tags: orm, doctrine

I'm getting this error whenever I try to remove/delete the entity "candidate":

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM candidate WHERE id = ?' with params {"1":3}: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ima`.`result`, CONSTRAINT `result_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`test_id`) REFERENCES `Test` (`id`))
```

Below are the relationships for the Doctrine ORM entities involved:

Entity: Candidate

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Test", mappedBy="candidate",
 * cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
private $tests;
```

Entity: Test

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Candidate", inversedBy="tests")
 * @JoinColumn(name="candidate_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
 */
private $candidate;

 /**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="test", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
private $answers;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Result", mappedBy="test", cascade={"persist"})
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
private $results;
```

Entity: Answer

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test", inversedBy="answers")
 * @JoinColumn(name="test_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $test;
```

Entity: Result

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test", inversedBy="results")
 */
protected $test;
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it with the tip from Gunner Aziz.

```
// Delete results.
$test = $candidate->getLatestTest();
$results = $test->getResults();
foreach ($results as $result) {
        $em->remove($result);
        $em->flush();
}

// Delete test.
$em->remove($test);
$em->flush();

// Delete candidate
$em->remove($candidate);
$em->flush();
```

The entity: 'Answer' will be automatically removed when I remove entity: 'Test' since its cascaded from there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete Candidates unless you delete corresponding Tests of that candidate. Its a db issue as if you delete the cadidates what will happen to the tests he took? On that foreign key it should have been `set null on delete`

also I see you have used `cascade={"persist"}` on your code in candidate class. So from [reference of doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) you need to delete those test first of that candidate then delete candidate itself()you can use other cascade methods too). Please see that paragraph as it explains your problem. Thanks